# Xorg Modesetting Driver Fails to Setup Screen Properly

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg

I noticed that my system's performance in 3D games was lackluster compared to what I experienced on Windows, so I searched for better graphics drivers on the Arch Linux wiki to find that it's suggested to use the modesetting driver instead of the `xf86-video-intel` driver (Can't post more than 2 links. Take my word for it, or search for the `Intel Graphics` page.). So, I uninstalled the `xf86-video-intel` driver, and setup an Xorg.conf file, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`. Despite searching everywhere for possible mistakes in my configuration, I couldn't figure out why I could only get one of my monitors to turn on my default.

My setup consists of the following:

- A laptop screen, `LVDS-1`.
- A Dell monitor, `HDMI-1`.
- A Sharp TV, `VGA-1`. This sends incorrect EDID data, so I use a custom mode to get a `1368x768` resolution.

The effect I want is for the laptop screen to be disabled, the Dell monitor to be the primary monitor, and the Sharp TV to be an extended monitor to the right of the Dell monitor.

This is my current configuration:

```
# DEVICES
Section "Device"
    Identifier              "Intel HD Graphics 4000"
    Driver                  "modesetting"
    Option "ModeDebug"      "true"
EndSection

# MONITORS

# Primary Dell Monitor
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier              "HDMI-1" # HDMI Port 1 - HDMI-1
    Option "Primary"        "true" # Primary

    Option "PreferredMode"  "1920x1080" # 1920x1080

    Option "Enable"         "true" # Enable
EndSection

# Extended Sharp TV
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier              "VGA-1" # VGA Port 1 - VGA-1
    Option "Primary"        "false" # Extended

    # Add custom mode, because TVs send inaccurate EDID data.
    Mode "1368x768"
        DotClock 85.25
        HTimings 1368 1440 1576 1784
        VTimings 768 771 781 798
        Flags "-HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    Option "PreferredMode"  "1368x768" # 1368x768

    Option "Enable"         "true" # Enable
EndSection

# Disabled Laptop Screen
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier              "LVDS-1" # Built In Screen

    Option "Enable"         "false" # Disable
EndSection

# SCREENS

Section "Screen"
    Identifier              "Screen 0"
    Device                  "Intel HD Graphics 4000"
    Monitor                 "HDMI-1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier              "Screen 1"
    Device                  "Intel HD Graphics 4000"
    Monitor                 "VGA-1"
EndSection

# SERVER LAYOUTS

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier              "Layout"
    Screen "Screen 0"
    Screen "Screen 1"       RightOf "Screen 0"
EndSection
```

When booting with this configuration, [this](https://pastebin.com/iZkLxxyb) is the log at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, note that I turned on modesetting debug messages. The important part here is the `(EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument`.

Out of curiosity, I tried booting *without* this configuration, moving `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` to my desktop. [This](https://pastebin.com/kUTRDUfU) was the result. Oddly enough, the `(EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument` still persists.

So, why is this error happening?

System info:

- OS: Linux 4.9.11-1-ARCH x86_64
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000
- DE: XFCE
- XRandR version: 1.5

Comment: confirmed on xfce2.14 on deb10, diff setup but also intel graphics, same error

Comment: @qrtLs IIRC I ended up writing a small Bash script to call xrandr and do what I needed it to do, and adding it to autostart with my terminal (including a sleep in case I needed to cancel it).